# CMFWorkflow and Marker Interfaces

Tags: workflow, plone

I'm currently prototyping a small project in Plone and trying to KISS as much as possible while the requirements are still in flux. To that end, I've resisted creating any custom content types for now and have been using marker interfaces to distinguish between "types" of content.

Now that I'm looking at workflow, I've realised that they're bound to types, and there doesn't seem to be a mechanism for assigning them to markers. I think I could wrap `portal_workflow` with my own version that looks for markers and returns the appropriate workflow if found, however, this doesn't feel like a tenable approach.

Is there a way of assigning workflow to markers that I've missed, or should I just bite the bullet and create some lightweight custom content types instead?

Comment: In this case, keeping it simple would have been to use new content types, perhaps. :-P

Comment: Yes, that was pretty much the conclusion once I realised I needed custom workflows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a built-in feature to use markers, but at http://www.martinaspeli.net/articles/dcworkflows-hidden-gems, Martin Aspeli hints that it is possible:

> Note that in Plone, the workflow chain of an object is looked up by
>   multi-adapting the object and the workflow to the IWorkflowChain
>   interface. The adapter factory should return a tuple of string
>   workflow names (IWorkflowChain is a specialisation of IReadSequence,
>   i.e. a tuple). The default obviously looks at the mappings in the
>   portal_workflow tool, but it is possible to override the mapping, e.g.
>   in resopnse to some marker interface.

Comment: Thanks, that's what made me think I could provide my own `portal_workflow` wrapper that handled this. I think custom types is going to be the right approach, although I've selected you as the solution because it does solve the stated problem :)

Comment: All correct; it's this interface that makes CMFPlacefulWorkflow possible. The full interface path is `Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.IWorkflowChain`. The default implementation lives in `Products.CMFPlone.workflow`.

Comment: Yes, doing full-fledged content types is probably a simpler path in the end.